# echo #? is not printing any kind of value

Tags: command-line, echo

When I enter some command in terminal and check whether that command worked or not by typing

```
echo #?
```

it is not printing any kind of integer value?

Is there any problem with my system? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Try `echo $?` instead of `echo #?`

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for exit code, which indicates success or failure of the previous command, run from the same session.

You need:

```
$?
```

So do:

```
echo $?
```

It will output an positive integer from 0 to 255, inclusive, where `0` meaning success and any other value meaning failed, with various values are used for indicating various reasons/causes of failure.

---

Now while you are doing:

```
echo #?
```

you will just see a newline, which is default behavior of `echo` without any argument. You don't have any argument here as anything starting with `#` becomes a comment in the command line, so `#?` is being treated as a comment.